# How to call function from template With Django

Tags: python, django

Please let me know in Django how to call method written from template html to view.
Also please tell me about how to pass variables.

```
class index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        text = "text"
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'text': text})

def Replace
    text = "Replaced"
    (I want to pass variable text to index html from here)
```

index.html is as follows

```
<p>{{ text }}<p>
<a html="{?????}">text replace</>
```

If you click "text replace" you want to call the function "Replace" to replace the variable "text".
Though it is a rudimentary question, thank you.

Comment: If you want to just replace the text within a certain tag, why not just use ajax?

Comment: The question code is just an example, I want to substitute variables with functions and pass variables to template.Without using ajax.

Comment: So do you want that function to be executed at the client's side(initiated by an action of any user) or while rendering the template?

Comment: The text replace must a function and it should have url to serve, so call the url in the template a tag. On clicking this the url will call the function 'Replace'

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your function then call it from with url then update template.

views.py

```
def replace(request):
         text = "replaced"
         return render(request, 'index.html', {'text': text})
```

in urls.py

```
 url(r'replace/$', views.replace, name='replace'),
```

in index.html

```
{{ text }}
<a href="url_to_the_function">Text Replace <a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Url tag in django template language:

```
<a href="{% url 'appName:urlName' %}"> replace </a>
```